# how to write/save a buffer content to a file in C using fprintf

Tags: c

I have a hidraw.c code below which I use "fprintf" to write the buffer content onto a file but it does not write the stdout to a specified file.  File is created but the file is empty.  Does anyone know how to approach this issue?   Complete source code can be found here:

https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/samples/hidraw/hid-example.c.html

Below is the code snippet which I need help on.  I'm a novice in C prog.

```
FILE *fp;
int loop = 10;
fp=fopen("test.txt", "a");
while (loop !=0)
{
    res = read(fd, buf, 16);
    if (res < 0) {
        perror("read");
    } else {
        printf("read() read %d bytes:\n\t", res);
        
        if(fp == NULL)
                exit(-1);

        for (i = 0; i < res; i++)
            /* This printf will print buffer in the real time */
            /*printf("%hhx ", buf[i]);*/
            /* This is to write buffer to a file  but this does not capture the data*/  
            fprintf(fp, "%hhx ", buf[i]);
    }
}
fclose(fp);
close(fd);
```

Comment: Why are you mixing unbuffered functions like `read` and buffered writes like `fprintf`? Usually for performance reasons you should stick with using all `FILE*` operations unless you have some specific needs, like you're using a socket.

Comment: What is `res` set to when reading? What is `buf` defined as?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  The major reasons it does not compiler are: 1) the needed `#include` statements are missing.  2) there is no function definition.

Comment: Read the documentation of [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and of [fprintf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html)

Comment: OT regarding: `fp=fopen("test.txt", "a");`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then report the failure to `stderr`.  This is not a recoverable error, so suggest the next statement be : `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `if(fp == NULL)
                    exit(-1);`  this should be immediately after the call to `fopen()`, not several statements later

Comment: What value did you get from the `printf()` that reports the number of bytes read.  You never decrement `loop` so your  code is going to run for a long time.  You don't show where you've defined `buf`.  You should probably print a newline every so often too.

Comment: regarding; `res = read(fd, buf, 16);`  The variable `fd` is not declared anywhere in the posted code

Comment: regarding; `if (res < 0) {
            perror("read");`  the code needs to ALSO check for ==0 (which indicates EOF)

Comment: regarding: `while (loop !=0)
    {
        res = read(fd, buf, 16);
        if (res < 0) {
            perror("read");`  MUCH better to use the call to `read()` to control the `while()` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding;

```
fprintf(fp, "%hhx ", buf[i]);
```

Assuming that the call to `fopen()` was successful

This is placing the bytes from `buf[]` into the output stream for the output file.   But NOT forwarding those bytes to the actual file.

Suggest, after the loop is completed:

```
fflush( fp );
```

Comment: @aqh999,  since this is a good answer, please 'upvote' the answer